# Причины приводящие к тому что приложение выдает ошибку при запуске, хотя компилируется и устанавливается

Tags: java, android

Учусь на курсах програмирование Java и Android. Такой вопрос, в контрольной нужны 3 причины. У меня только 2.

1. Не прописал Activity в AndroidManifest.
2. При перезаписи метода onStart не вызвал его с super

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onStart(){   
   ausgabe =+"onStart";  
   tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
   ```

Нужен еще один вариант. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: любое исключение не перехваченное в onStart/onCreate Activity/Application

Comment: и кстати со 2 пунктом если скомпилируется - меняйте компилятор.

Comment: объекты null при обращении, деление на 0, выход за пределы диапазона массива и любые причины приводящие к Runtime Exception, [их десятки](http://src-code.net/tipy-isklyuchenij-runtimeexception-i-error/)

Comment: @pavel, А почему оно не должно скомпилироваться?

Answer (score 4):

> Не прописал Activity в AndroidManifest.

Вам нужны причины, по которым приложение выдаст ошибку **при запуске**.

Если Вы не пропишите launcher activity в манифесте, то приложение просто не соберется.

Если Вы не пропишите какую-либо другую activity в манифесте, то приложение вылетит с ошибкой, но не при непосредственном старте приложения, а при запуске этой activity.

В качестве требуемых причин можно указать любые ситуации, в результате которых возникают unchecked-исключения:

1. `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

   ```
   int[] array = new int[1];
   int a = array[2];
   ```
2. `ArithmeticException`:

   ```
   float a = 5/0;
   ```
3. `StackOverflowError` в результате бесконечной рекурсии:

   ```
   private void foo() {
       foo();
   }

   ...

   foo();
   ```

Также можно воспроизвести исключения именно из Android SDK, например, `Resources$NotFoundException`:

```
String s = getString(0);
```

Comment: NullPointerExeption самая распространенная причина падения при выполнении приложения, особенно в android :)

Answer (score 1):

если про распространенные то думаю, и те которые относятся непосредственно к запуску, в добавок к "Не прописал Activity в AndroidManifest"

- обращение к не проинициализрованным компонентам лаяута (например findViewById прив ссылке на ID которого нет на вашем лаяуте, но есть на другом,например, вернет null)
- большое количество вложенных вьюх. (StackOverflowError) если не ошибаюсь - больше 15
- отображение тяжелых картинок из ресурсов (out of memory)

хватит?